# Is this a counter example to the Eulerian Trail definition?

Tags: graph-theory, examples-counterexamples, eulerian-path

Wikipedia says:

> An undirected graph has an Eulerian trail if and only if exactly zero or two vertices have odd degree, and all of its vertices with nonzero degree belong to a single connected component.

However, I was able to produce this graph which appears to

1. Break the definition (all 8 vertices have an odd degree of 3)
2. Allow for a Eulerian path: $A\to C\to E\to G\to D\to F\to H\to B$

[image: counter-example graph]

Is there something I missed/misunderstood here?

Comment: That's not an Eulerian path.

Answer (score 1):

Whoops, I misread. The definition of a Eulerian trail is a path that visits every **edge** exactly once, not every **vertex**.

The concept I was thinking of is called a [Hamiltonian path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) which visits each vertex exactly once.

Comment: That would be a *Hamiltonian* path.